# How can I validate a REstate Schematic that I accept from my API?

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a REST API around REstate for a work-internal project and I want to validate the data the client sends is a valid Schematic without adding complex validation logic to my API overall.

Is there any quick way for me to do this check in my controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily add an extension method that will cleanly validate the Schematic using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator` and can `out` the results on failure.

```cs
public static class SchematicValidatorExtensions
{
    public static bool TryValidate<TState, TInput>(
        this Schematic<TState, TInput> schematic, 
        out ICollection<ValidationResult> results)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(schematic, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(
            schematic, context, results,
            validateAllProperties: true
        );
    }
}
```

You can then validate it by calling it on the Schematic.

```cs
var isValid = schematic.TryValidate(out var results);
```